# Port Tunneling for windows

Tags: port, amazon-web-services, tunnel

I have one AWS instance with public IP <52.14.142.152>. Now I have installed one application on port 5555 and able to access the same from internet.
I have installed another instance of same application on port 6666 , but not able to access the same from internet .Both the application is accessible from localhost.

Comment: Are you sure this particular application supports being installed twice?  It is very likely the two instances are in conflict.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Answer (score 0):

Allow port 6666 on the Security Group.

And also check any host firewall on your (Windows) machine.